# Modem 2640u turned off between update firmware and the update did not complete

Tags: firmware, dsl-modem

When my modem device was update firmware, power disconnected and firmware update not complete. after that when I turn on my ADSL modem, not show the pannel by 192.168.1.1 and lights of power and internet are on only.
What can I do?

[image: 2640u]

Comment: Most likely, the recovery process is more complicated than something you'll be able to do yourself. It usually involves something like pushing new firmware to the router using `tftp` and then holding down the router's reset button as you apply power to it.

Comment: @David Schwartz can you give me more information about tftp? How does work?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't matter. This particular router model doesn't support CFE recovery. Try the 30-30-30 reset in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model has no CFE recovery. So your only choice is a 30-30-30 reset. If that doesn't do it, the modem is bricked. That is, it is now as useful as a brick.

To do a 30-30-30 reset:

1. Unplug the modem, wait a few seconds, plug it back in.
2. Wait for the lights to stabilize.
3. Hold the reset button down for 30 seconds.
4. Keeping the reset button down, unplug the modem and wait 30 seconds.
5. Still keeping the reset button down, plug the modem back in.
6. Wait 30 seconds.
7. Release the reset button. Wait a few minutes.

If the process worked, the router will be working and restored to factory settings. If it didn't work, recovery is not possible without extreme measures.

Comment: not helped me :\

Answer (score 1):

is there a reset button on the back of the modem? if so, hold it down until the modem powers down and starts back up again. if you are lucky, it will work. unfortunately losing power while performing an firmware update can permanently disable the device, in which case you need to contact your service provider for a replacement.

Comment: I used the hard reset but it didn't work!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. hopefully David Schwartz's advice will help. unfortunately flashing firmware is just plain dangerous, but much safer than it was 10 years ago.